# How I can click the same jsf command button twice?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I open a popup using the jsf command button. After closing the popup, when I click the same button again, I cannot open the popup. So when I click the same button twice, I cannot open it. When I debug and look at it, the debug point does not fall into the method. What could be the reason for this? How can I solve this?

**My commandButton:**

```
<a4j:commandButton id="me_ge_knowledge" value="Knowledge"
    actionListener="#{knowledgeBean.setPkByPage(column.id)}"
    render="knowledgePopup"
    oncomplete="#{rich:component('mt_knowledge_popup')}.show();">
</a4j:commandButton>
```

Comment: Check your browser's JavaScript console for errors